# Metadata in PDF Files

Tags: pdf-generation, tagged-pdf

I want to be able to store some plugin-specific data in a PDF so that I can read it back when that PDF is loaded back, without this metadata being visible to the user.

How can I put this metadata into the PDF File?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF supports XMP metadata. You should append your plug-in specific information as a payload in the XMP portion.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are generating and reading your PDFs you can use [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) to edit your metadata.  You can add an invisable tag to the PDF by adding it as a metadata property with a key and value by using pdftk dump_data to write all metadata to a text file, then append the new key and value to the text file, then use pdftk update_info to put back all the metadata, including the new key value pair.

Comment: It's GPL. Good Luck with linking that.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do that is simply append the information as text to the end of the pdf file.

Comment: but how do i make sure the user does not see it