# Adding metadata to PDF generated using Wicked PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, metadata, wicked-pdf

I'm using [Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) to generate a PDF from HTML. I've seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757192/metadata-in-pdf-files) on adding metadata to a PDF, and it suggests using XMP metadata. How can I use Wicked PDF to add XMP metadata to a generated PDF?

Comment: did u find an answer for this?

Comment: I think that since this gem is just a wrapper for command line program `wkhtmltopdf`, and this program does not support adding metadata, you are out of luck.  Maybe someone will come up with a "patcher" that lets you add metadata after Wicked has written the page, but this would be ugly.  Note that `prawn` writes metadata, but this is not useful since you're starting with HTML.

Comment: @Gene yes,i did it using prawn...with wicked-pdf i can add the title to the pdf using the html `<title>` tag,but meta tags `<meta>` dont work

Comment: I'm also pretty sure the final answer is that Wicked PDF just doesn't support it, and you should use something else (like Prawn, as @Gene suggested).

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the original document using Prawn as you say, then just use the `info` attribute to set the meta-data you need.  See [the manual](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf) and search for `:info`.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say Wicked PDF adds a title.  PDF documents don't have titles (although sections and subsections can in the outline).  See [this discussion, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528240/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-a-pdf-document-to-appear-as-the-page-title).

Comment: PDF documents don't have titles? Unless you count the 'Title' entry in the Document Information Dictionary. Which Adobe Reader lists under Document Properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add metadata directly with WickedPDF, you might try using another library to add the metadata after the PDF is generated (a two step process).

I found an SO answer that suggests [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) might be able to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18536830/473691.